# Gower distance matrix vs. One-hot encoding for mixed (nominal-ordinal, categorical, continuous) datasets

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, autoencoder, data-preprocessing

What will be the best practice for preprocessing mixed datasets? Gower distance matrix of a mixed dataset or one-hot encoded nominal columns of the same dataset?

Gower distance matrix gave me umap chart on a train dataset as you can see below. [image: UMAP input: gower distance matrix]

If I one-hot encoded nominal dataset columns with pandas `pd.get_dummies(dataset)` I got umap chart shown on picture [image: UMAP input: one-hot encoded nominal columns].

Continuous columns are standardized and min-max scaled between [0,1] in both case of dilemma.

My goal is one of these results (gower or one-hot encoded) use as an input in UMAP or an autoencoder. Then get clusters with the aim of recognizing outliers on a test dataset.

Comment: Maybe I need one-hot encoding and then gower distance? What will be the best input for machine learning algorithms as well as for dimensionality reduction algorithms like UMAP?

Comment: Could I input gower distance matrix in autoencoder? It is simplier then building autonecoder layer for nominal variables, layer for continuous variables and the loss function for the mentioned ones.